# Returning a map of structs from within a class (where the struct definition is within the class): compile error

Tags: c++, class, struct

I have a class, and within that class I define a struct. The struct has overloaded comparison operators so that it can be used with a map (with an int as the key).

Prior to messing with classes, I had the struct defined in a .cc file, and that file also contained a function which returned a map of this struct. It worked.

Now I want to have the struct defined in the class header, and the class should have a function which returns a map of structs.

Here is a simplified version of my code, which compiles with the same error as the full version. I don't understand the error, and would appreciate any help!

Cheers.

**myclass.h:**

```
#include <map>

class myclass {
  public:
    struct mystruct {
      int i;
      mystruct();
      mystruct(int j);

      bool operator==(const mystruct& rhs);
      bool operator>(const mystruct& rhs);
      bool operator<(const mystruct& rhs);
    };

    ::std::map<int,mystruct> getStructMap();
};
```

**myclass.cc:**

```
#include <map>
#include "myclass.h"

myclass::mystruct::mystruct(int j) : i(j) {};
myclass::mystruct::mystruct() : i(-1) {};

bool ::myclass::mystruct::operator==(const ::myclass::mystruct& rhs) {return i==rhs.i; }
bool ::myclass::mystruct::operator>(const ::myclass::mystruct& rhs) {return i>rhs.i; }
bool ::myclass::mystruct::operator<(const ::myclass::mystruct& rhs) {return i<rhs.i; }


::std::map<int,::myclass::mystruct> ::myclass::getStructMap() {
  ::std::map<int,::myclass::mystruct> structMap;
  for (int i=0;i<5;i++) structMap[i]=::myclass::mystruct(i);
  return structMap;
}
```

**myprogram.cc:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include "myclass.h"

int main() {    
  myclass myobj;
  ::std::map<int,::myclass::mystruct> mymap;
  mymap=myobj.getStructMap();   
}
```

**compile error:**

```
> g++ -o myprogram myprogram.cc myclass.cc
myclass.cc:12: error: ‘class std::map<int, myclass::mystruct, std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int, myclass::mystruct> > >::myclass’ has not been declared
myclass.cc:12: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘getStructMap’ with no type
myclass.cc: In function ‘int getStructMap()’:
myclass.cc:15: error: cannot convert ‘std::map<int, myclass::mystruct, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, myclass::mystruct> > >’ to ‘int’ in return
```

Comment: The operators and `getStructMap()` all should be `const`

Comment: Fair point - I'm very bad at "const"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently your code in parsed as

```
/*missing type*/ ::std::map<int,::myclass::mystruct>::myclass::getStructMap()
```

Thus, first error, `map` doesn't have `myclass` member (or subclasses, method, typedef, ...)
then the second error : no return type (so assuming `int` and thus the conversion error).

So to solve that, in myclass.cc, you may remove extra `::` as follow:

```
::std::map<int,::myclass::mystruct> myclass::getStructMap() {
```

or add extra parenthesis:

```
::std::map<int,::myclass::mystruct> (::myclass::getStructMap()) {
```